# Allow User to Re-Order DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcombobox

I have a Datagridview that is bound to a DataTable.

I have added DataGridViewComboBoxColumn to the Datagridview that is has a data property relating to  an existing column in the bound DataTable.

Everything works as expected, apart from the fact that at run time, the user is able to re-order every column barring the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.

Here is the code for implementing the added Column :-

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn TaskEntryCombo = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
            TaskEntryCombo.HeaderText = "Report Name";
            TaskEntryCombo.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
            TaskEntryCombo.DataSource = ReportTable;
            TaskEntryCombo.DataPropertyName = "TaskName";
            TaskEntryCombo.DisplayMember = "ReportName";
            TaskEntryCombo.ValueMember = "ReportName";
            TaskEntryCombo.MaxDropDownItems = 35;

dgvTemplate.Columns.Add(TaskEntryCombo);
```

Any Ideas on whatI need to set to allow this? The User is not able to access the column Header for this particular colum and re-order the grid based on the values in the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
TaskEntryCombo.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic
```

> Automatic : The user can sort the column by clicking the column header
>   unless the column headers are used for selection. A sorting glyph will
>   be displayed automatically.